# Change Centos Mysql sa password

Tags: centos, mysql

I have just come to realise that mysql on centos has a user account sa and I want to remove this account or set a password on it. There is no entry in the mysql.user table so a set password statement doesn't work.

Is it possible to set a password?

mysql -u sa

will get you to a mysql> prompt with limited access.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the anonymous user.

To get rid: try this (as mysql root):

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You may also want to get rid of test access:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE db LIKE 'tes%' AND user='';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Alternatively, these steps (and more) can be automatically taken care of by running the mysql_secure_installation script.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-secure-installation.html

Comment: Thank you, it was the anonymous user, DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;  did clear out the issue :)

Comment: Glad it helped, please accept the answer if it has solved your problem :-)